# How to sequentially execute a command on every file in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, scripting

I have a directory I'm polling through cron for new uploads and I'm
running a sequence of scripts on each upload.

one part of the program retrieves an image from the web using the name of the uploaded file.

The image is saved with a generic name, image.png, it then gets sent to the next script for more processing.

only one image is made, so if there are 5 newly uploaded files only 1 image still gets made.

How do I structure the code/scripts so that the full cycle of the program which I have in 3 different scripts get run only on one file at a time, in other words loop through the directory and run the program on each file sequentially.

I'm just trying to preserve the structure of 1 image file being made but all uploads being processed.

```
           shopt -s nullglob

           for file in /home/yt/box/moremusic/youtube/*;
           do
           python /home/yt/ytimage.py $file;
           /home/yt/uploadyt;
           done;

           shopt -u nullglob
```

I tried that script with 3 files in /home/yt/box/moremusic/youtube/
and only 1 image was retrieved.

How can I achieve my goal or at least get in the right path?
Or Actually How can I process all of the uploaded files in parallel and still only have 1 image file.

Answer (score -1):

Try a bash loop:

```
ls -1 | while read file; do
    echo $file;
done;
```